# how to extract value JSON in Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, json

here is my MSSQL query to count total rows in my table.

select count(0) from Branches

and below is the result in JSON

```
    {
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "": "8"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "": "8"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        1
    ]
}
```

im trying to get the value in recordset with **result.recordset[0]**
but result is not what I want. I want only value ( number 8 ).
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can either access the data as is by referencing the empty key

```
result.recordset[0][""]
```

Or alternatively, use an alias for the `COUNT` field in your SQL query for better readability

```
SELECT COUNT(0) AS BranchCount FROM Branches
```

Then you can reference using the alias

```
result.recordset[0]["BranchCount"]
```